# How to make the context linked to each user in the telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, openai-api, aiogram

I need different users to have a different context and not one common one. So that there are different answers for each user.
Here is my code where all users have the same context:

```
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import json
from datetime import datetime



file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

openai.api_key = config['openai']
bot = Bot(config['token'])
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": ""},
        {"role": "user", "content": ""},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": ""},
        #{"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
    ]


def update(messages, role, content):
    messages.append({"role": role, "content": content})
    return messages


#personal messages
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"], chat_type=["private"])
async def echo(message : types.Message):
    update(messages, "user", message.text)
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
        temperature = 1,
        #max_tokens=4096
        presence_penalty = 1
    )
    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
    # saving a message to a log file
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_name = message.from_user.username if message.from_user.username else message.from_user.first_name
    message_text = message.text
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    log_data = {
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "user_id": user_id,
        "user_name": user_name,
        "message": message_text
    }
    with open("updates.log", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(log_data, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
        print(log_data)
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

I tried to do this using SQLite to save the context in the database. But it's bad enough in this and the maximum that I got is this misunderstanding:
**(This code is not working!)**

```
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import json
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3

file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

openai.api_key = config['openai']
bot = Bot(config['token'])
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    context TEXT
)
''')
conn.close()



def get_context(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT context FROM users WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.close()
    if row:
        return json.loads(row[0])
    else:
        return []

def save_context(user_id, context):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users (user_id, context) VALUES (?, ?)', (user_id, json.dumps(context)))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"], chat_type=["private"])
async def echo(message : types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    context = get_context(user_id)
    messages = [{"role": "system", "content": ""}] + context + [{"role": "user", "content": message.text}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
        temperature=1,
        # max_tokens=4096
        presence_penalty=1
    )
    await message.answer(response.choices[0].text)
    context = response.choices[0].context
    save_context(user_id, context)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to approach this, but to provide different contexts for each user, you can store the conversation history and context for each user separately. You mentioned `sqlite`, so that is what I used (`contexts.db`):

```
import openai
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import json
from datetime import datetime


# Initialize database
conn = sqlite3.connect('contexts.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table to store user contexts
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contexts
             (user_id text PRIMARY KEY, context text)''')

# Load OpenAI API key and Telegram Bot token from config.json
file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

openai.api_key = config['openai']
bot = Bot(config['token'])
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


# Get context for user from database
def get_context(user_id):
    c.execute("SELECT context FROM contexts WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row:
        return json.loads(row[0])
    else:
        return []


# Save context for user to database
def save_context(user_id, context):
    c.execute("REPLACE INTO contexts (user_id, context) VALUES (?, ?)",
              (user_id, json.dumps(context)))
    conn.commit()


# Update conversation history and context
def update(context, messages, role, content):
    messages.append({"role": role, "content": content})
    context["messages"] = messages
    return context


# Handler for personal messages
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"], chat_type=["private"])
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    # Get user ID and context
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    context = get_context(user_id)

    # Update conversation history and context
    messages = context.get("messages", [])
    messages = update(context, messages, "user", message.text)

    # Get response from OpenAI API
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="davinci",
        prompt="\n".join([m["content"] for m in messages]),
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1024,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0,
        stop=["\n"]
    )

    # Update conversation history and context with response
    messages = update(context, messages, "assistant",
                       response.choices[0].text.strip())

    # Save context to database
    save_context(user_id, context)

    # Send response to user
    await message.answer(response.choices[0].text.strip())

    # Log message
    user_name = message.from_user.username if message.from_user.username else message.from_user.first_name
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    log_data = {
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "user_id": user_id,
        "user_name": user_name,
        "message": message.text,
        "response": response.choices[0].text.strip()
    }
    with open("updates.log", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(log_data, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```